# What does a phantom technician do on a production set and why would a director need one?

Tags: video, production

I just saw a video and in the credits is listed "phantom technician" ?
What are this person's duties, and why would a director need one on a production set?

Here is the video reference:
https://vimeo.com/23141142

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was shot with a [Phantom HD](http://www.visionresearch.com/Products/High-Speed-Cameras/Phantom-HDGOLD/) camera. It's a special high-speed digital camera that can shoot at up to 1,500 fps (which is what the creators say they were shooting at). So he's likely the tech who setup this camera rig.

Comment: Thank you so much. Had no idea that they made a camera that could shoot HD so fast and so nicely, so it wasn't Twixtor. :>

Comment: Sure thing. Phantom footage is just incredible. Do a search in Vimeo and be amazed. Imagine what Twixtor could do with 1,500 fps!

Comment: superfragilisticexpialidocious (this comment field won't let just say 'cool' 10 letter min.)  :>

Answer (score 1):

A phantom tech is someone who basically operates the high speed camera.  Everything from initial set up to shooting to transfer of footage.  The camera itself is quite complex, so it requires a little bit of knowledge, and tons of experience as it really is nothing like any other camera, with that said, the footage is incredible